# God's presence among us

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity

I have a simple question: why does God not live with us directly? It seems He is revealing Himself to us only indirectly, as opposed to being with us as Someone we could reach just like another person. He did it once, why not do it in perpetuity?

Answers from Trinitarian Christians, please.

Comment: please specify which denomination you'd like an answer from, as the answer may differ

Comment: When you say God lived with us once, do you refer to Christ Jesus?

Comment: @Lesley yes, that's what I had in mind

Comment: Every answer here is going to be speculation. Since God doesn't tell us this, we can make guesses but we can't know for sure.

Comment: 'Immanuel' is a name given to the promised Messiah, who is now come - Jesus Christ. 'Immanuel' means, 'God with us'. (see Matthew 1:23.) Now risen and ascended, God is still among us (in Spirit) if we be penitent, believing and if we be gathered properly. If gathered correctly, one will come in among the assembled and fall down and say 'Surely God is among you of a truth'. (See 1 Corinthians 14:25.) Is your question about the _failure_ of 'Christians' among whom God, clearly, does _not_ dwell ? Up-voted +1.

Comment: @DJClayworth When you claim that God doesn't tell us; we can guess but cannot know for sure, you are speaking for yourself. Every answer here bar one (so far) has detailed myriad Bible texts that explain the now revealed mystery of Christ in us, the hope of glory. Paul revealed that mystery (Eph.6:19). There is remarkable unity of thought in trinitarian answers given, and dozens of texts pointed to; we are in agreement and thank God for this revelation in Christ!

Comment: What happened to Jesus?

Comment: @Frank-God can and does live with man "directly."  Just not physically though, but He indwells believers spiritually by the "Baptism of the Holy Ghost" (which is God).  Physically would be too limiting, whereas through the indwelling of the Holy Spirit God is able to be with all His disciples anywhere they may be:  in church, or in jail, at home, or on the stormy seas.  The feeling of "Christ in you" is unmatched by any other religious experience.  And the wisdom, direction, comfort He gives   is invaluable!  Seek the Charismatic ... you'll find the personable God!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Trinitarian answer would be in this lecture [Divine Indwelling and the Presence of God](https://soundcloud.com/thomisticinstitute/divine-indwelling-and-the-presence-of-god-fr-dominic-legge-op) where Fr. Legge discusses 3 ways God is present to us: 1) in the order of being; 2) through the Trinitarian life / grace; 3) through the Incarnation & subsequent presence of the glorified Jesus in the Eucharist (see lecture [Entering Into Christ's Passion: The Mass as a Sacrifice](https://soundcloud.com/thomisticinstitute/entering-into-christs-passion-the-mass-as-a-sacrifice-fr-dominic-legge-op)).  Yes, the first 2 are not visible, Jesus's incarnation was in the past, and the presence in the Eucharist is spiritual.  One classic explanation by Aquinas is in another lecture *Aquinas on the Incarnation*: [part 1](https://soundcloud.com/thomisticinstitute/aquinas-on-the-incarnation-part-1-fr-thomas-joseph-white-op) and [part 2](https://soundcloud.com/thomisticinstitute/aquinas-on-the-incarnation-part-ii-fr-thomas-joseph-white-op-1) discussing why one time incarnation in the "middle" of human history makes sense and "convenient".

Rather than giving a summary of the above lectures (I plan to transcribe those lectures one day), the simple answer is this:

- In the OT the Israelites felt God's presence among them and the fullness of God's presence was tangible when Jesus walked on earth.
- It is God's intention that the memory of God's dealings with Israel and the account of His incarnation in Jesus were preserved in the Bible, which is YET another mode of presence for Christians when they read the Bible or when they hear the word of God preached.
- In addition, the Trinitarian life is God's gift to us to make Him present in our hearts for those who are willing to receive it and be baptized.
- Then Christ is also present to us in the Eucharist in masses celebrated throughout the world in the past 2,000 years or so, and in the foreseeable future.
- Another mode of presence is in the church, through the acts of the believers showing love, comfort, and forgiveness in abundance.
- Finally, Jesus will BE fully and visibly present in the life to come in the new Heaven and Earth after evil is fully vanquished and after the resurrection of the bodies of believers; this is every Christian's hope.

Another classic argument is that were God fully present and visible it would not preserve our free will and thus *not* giving us opportunity to be "trained" to voluntarily orient our lives toward the Ultimate Good.  He could have been more obvious and could have written with big letters in the sky in multiple languages every morning:

> "Dear humans, I am here and waiting for your decision to repent, become Christian, read your Bible and come to mass"

but (as explained in the lectures linked above) He decided to use another approach.

Answer (score 6):

> 15 “If you love me, keep my commands. 16 And I will ask the Father,
> and he will give you another advocate to help you and be with you
> forever— 17 the Spirit of truth. The world cannot accept him, because
> it neither sees him nor knows him. But you know him, for he lives with
> you and will be in you. 18 **I will not leave you as orphans; I will
> come to you.** 19 Before long, the world will not see me anymore, but
> you will see me. Because I live, you also will live. 20 On that day
> you will realize that I am in my Father, and you are in me, and I am
> in you. (John 14:15-20)

> 7 But very truly I tell you, it is for your good that I am going away.
> **Unless I go away, the Advocate will not come to you; but if I go, I
> will send him to you.** 8 When he comes, he will prove the world to be
> in the wrong about sin and righteousness and judgment: 9 about sin,
> because people do not believe in me; 10 about righteousness, because I
> am going to the Father, where you can see me no longer; 11 and about
> judgment, because the prince of this world now stands condemned. (John 16:7-11)

Jesus told his disciples point blank that he could not send the Holy Spirit unless He went away.

If you study Ecclesiastes 3, you will find that we must pass through many times in life. Two of them are "a time to weep" and "a time to mourn". They are part of growing up into a mature person. When Jesus died on the cross, that was "a time to weep" on a worldwide scale. God has His purposes in conforming the world to this sequence of times, in small within our individual lives, and in large, to liberate the whole world. Part of the time God's presence with us is obvious, and other times he seems to be absent.

Job cried out because God seemed distant to him. He needed someone close by to help him. However, if you study Job's words in the speeches before God shows up, you can find that the man had a deep understanding of the nature of the savior. In the middle of saying, "I can't see you, God!" Job was revealing mysteries of God. That is because the suffering Job was enduring was a channel for God to pour wisdom into him. There is no other way for God to communicate such truths. Even Christ was made perfect through suffering.

> 8 Son though he was, he learned obedience from what he suffered 9 and,
> once made perfect, he became the source of eternal salvation for all
> who obey him 10 and was designated by God to be high priest in the
> order of Melchizedek. (Hebrews 5:8-10)

Among the forms of suffering we must endure, one of the deepest is loneliness. In Genesis, loneliness is the first thing in all creation that is named as not good. (See Genesis 2:18). Thus the first sign of faith is trusting that God is with you even though you cannot see Him.

When Jesus hung on the cross, the pain of whipping and nails and lungs about to burst was intense, but what did Jesus cry out? "My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?" This was the greatest trial that Jesus was made to endure, the feeling that his Father had deserted him. It is when he then offers his spirit up to that Father anyway that Jesus' complete faith is made manifest.

As Luke said, "*The student is not above the teacher, but everyone who is fully trained will be like their teacher.*" (Luke 6:40)

Answer (score 3):

In our present state, we could not take the direct presence of God. Not since Adam and Eve felt the need to hide from him (Genesis ch3 v8). In fact man "cannot see God and live" (Exodus ch33 v20).

Men were able to see the Son born as man, but the Son has now "ascended", so that he is now "hidden" from us (Colossians ch3 v3).

BUT living in the direct presence of God is promised for the future. "So we shall always be with the Lord" (1 Thessalonians ch4 v17)."Behold, the dwelling of God is with men. He shall dwell with them, and they shall be his people" (Revelation ch21 v3).

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer from a Reformed Protestant point of view is that God never turned his back on humanity, though humanity turned away from their Creator. Right from the start, God knew what he would do to deal with human corruption and sin, and in the fullness of time, while we were still helpless sinners, he sent his only-begotten Son into the world to deal with our sin, which creates a chasm between us and God.

Although no man can see God and live, men beheld the Word who became flesh (John 1:1-14). He showed them the Father in word and deed, explaining that to see him was to see the Father (John 14:6-9). He said that those safely in his hand were in the hand of the Father (John 10:28-29). He said that the Son leads people to the Father, and the Father leads people to the Son (Matthew 11:27 & John 6:65). Faith in the Son is the way to the Father.

God's presence is through the indwelling Holy Spirit (Romans 8:9 & 15-17). He is our guarantee of "Christ in us, the hope of glory" (Colossians 1:27). We have been assured in God's written word of the believer's wonderful awareness of God:

> "Being justified by faith, we have peace with God through our Lord
> Jesus Christ: by whom also we have access by faith into this grace
> wherein we stand, and rejoice in hope of the glory of God... because
> the love of God is shed abroad in our hearts by the Holy Spirit which
> is given unto us. For when we were yet without strength, in due time
> Christ died for the ungodly... But God commendeth his love toward us,
> in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us. Romans 5:1-8
> KJV

All three in the Godhead combine to 'disclose' God to those who have repentantly put total faith in what the Son of God did to restore us to the Father (John 14:15-21).

We cannot reach God in ways we think we should, for he is not "another person". God is Spirit and dwells in heaven, in unapproachable light, and "Without holiness, no-one will see the Lord" (Hebrews 12:14). We have to be purified and submit to God's refining. That is a lifetime process which only begins once we bend our knees in faith in Jesus' name and trust utterly in what he did to restore us to God. All of this is explained in God's word, the Bible. ***Soak up these scriptures and prayerfully learn how to draw close to God, through faith. He is only a prayer away, for those who trust and believe.***

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question... OP did not ask "how does one come close to God". You state in your answer that he is not "another person", but I don't see any explanation for why not, which is the question.

Comment: @user132647 God is not like "other persons" whom we reach out to. Man-made gods are supposed to be like us, but the God of the Bible states why there appears to be an indirect approach, but also how through his Holy Spirit he does directly presence himself with those who put faith in his Son. The Q presupposes this does not happen yet many answers here show that it does, and in perpetuity. But those who do draw close to God  as per James 4:8 find he is close to them, present with them. Jesus said he and his Father will make their abode with them John 14:23.

Comment: I thought that the question is very clear, but maybe the word "why" is not showing on your monitor.

Comment: @user132647 The OP has not expressed any difficulty seeing the "why not" part in my answer. I stated why not, with "our sin, which creates a chasm between us and God... Although no man can see God and live... God is Spirit and dwells in heaven, in unapproachable light, and "Without holiness, no-one will see the Lord" (Hebrews 12:14)." Those are the reasons why God does not live directly with us. But the OP has chosen an accepted answer, so there's no point in you going on about this point to me, is there?

Comment: I agree that it seems pointless. I wish you the best.

Answer (score 3):

Immanuel' is a name given to the promised Messiah, who is now come - Jesus Christ. 'Immanuel' means, 'God with us'. (see Matthew 1:23.)

Now risen and ascended, God is still among us (in Spirit) if we be penitent, believing and if we be gathered properly.

If gathered correctly, one will come in among the assembled and fall down and say 'Surely God is among you of a truth'. (See 1 Corinthians 14:25.)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question... OP did not ask if God is present in spirit, they asked why God is not present as a person.

Comment: @user132647 Jesus said 'God is Spirit' John 4:24. He is present _in person_ when he is present _in Spirit_. How else shall his person be present ? ? ?

Comment: How else??? In the way that literally every human ever alive has been present, isn't that obvious? He could be present in the same way that Joe Biden is present. He could give press conferences, be on TV, whatever. Obviously, he is not. Why not? That is the question.

Comment: @user132647 Are you not aware that He is ascended ? And that He will imminently return ? ? ? And that He is , even this moment, with us in Spirit ?

Comment: The question is "WHY". It's OK if you can't answer it, neither can I, but try to understand what's being asked.

Comment: @user132647 The answer to the question is that God _is_ with us. (But not if one does not believe He is.)

Comment: Please read the question. It is very clear. I can't help you any better than this.

Answer (score 2):

### People are totally evil. They hate God and they'd only sin harder.

Counterintuitive, right?
But consider:

1. When Jesus walked the earth, how was he received?

- The Caperneumites tried to throw him off a cliff.
- The Nazarenes called him a madman.
- The entire class of religious historians rejected him.
- The Pharisees were incensed at verifiable miracles right in front of their faces at least twice, and plotted to kill him.
- The Jews (esp their leaders) and Romans stuck him on a torture device and murdered him.

Consider his words on the topic:

> The world cannot hate you, but it does hate me because I testify about it-that its works are evil.

John 15

> "If the world hates you, understand that it hated me before it hated you. If you were of the world, the world would love you as its own. However, because you are not of the world, but I have chosen you out of it, the world hates you..... But this happened so that the statement written in their law might be fulfilled: They hated me for no reason."

2. Consider Moses. Psalm 78 is a neat summary. God *repeatedly* did *major* miracles *in their full sight* and even showed up himself. The presence at Sinai, the plagues of Egypt, the Red Sea, the manna, the water from the rock (twice), the bitter water, the bronze serpent....etc etc. Moses himself almost wouldn't believe God even as God told him he'd be a leader five times, out of the burning bush.
3. Jesus and Moses weren't exceptions:

Consider Mat 23:

> This is why I am sending you prophets, sages, and scribes. Some of them you will kill and crucify, and some of them you will flog in your synagogues and pursue from town to town. So all the righteous blood shed on the earth will be charged to you, from the blood of righteous Abel to the blood of Zechariah, son of Berechiah, whom you murdered between the sanctuary and the altar.

Or Hebrews 11;

> who through faith conquered kingdoms, enforced justice, obtained promises, stopped the mouths of lions, quenched the power of fire, escaped the edge of the sword, were made strong out of weakness, became mighty in war, put foreign armies to flight. Women received back their dead by resurrection. Some were tortured, refusing to accept release, so that they might rise again to a better life. Others suffered mocking and flogging, and even chains and imprisonment. They were stoned, they were sawn in two, they were killed with the sword. They went about in skins of sheep and goats, destitute, afflicted, mistreated- of whom the world was not worthy-wandering about in deserts and mountains, and in dens and caves of the earth.

4. Speaking of Abel:
   God spoke to Cain directly both before and after he murdered Abel. Did it help? No and no.
5. And let's not forget mum and dad in the garden:
   With no sin nature, no external pressure and the presence of God, how'd they go?
6. Which brings us to the best example, Satan: Formerly an archangel in the direct presence of God..... The demons know both the truth about God, what they were, and what is coming to them, see the demon Legion's question to Jesus: "What have we to do with you, Jesus? Have you come to torture us before the time?"
   Do they care?

I wouldn't normally encourage the contemplation of the motivations of Satan too much, but regarding this question it's telling.

## What mankind needs is God in us, not in our line of sight.

The latter does very little good at all. You could put us all in heaven and we would hate it and rebel out of pure spite even though we know it's futile...just like Satan still does.

## Some people have that

In John 16:7 it is recorded Jesus said it was to our advantage (!) that he went away, so that the Holy Spirit would come.

## When *those* people are put in the presence of God, it actually works

Revelation 21 and 22:

> And I saw no temple in the city, for its temple is the Lord God the Almighty and the Lamb. And the city has no need of sun or moon to shine on it, for the glory of God gives it light, and its lamp is the Lamb. By its light will the nations walk, and the kings of the earth will bring their glory into it, and its gates will never be shut by day-and there will be no night there. They will bring into it the glory and the honor of the nations. But nothing unclean will ever enter it, nor anyone who does what is detestable or false, but only those who are written in the Lamb's book of life.

## Repent and be saved

It's very easy to have God in you. Recognise that you are such a jerk that you would reject God right in front of you the way you are, and cannot do anything but sin. Then have faith that Jesus will save you and all you need do is believe. His Spirit will then live in you. Which is what people - including you - actually need.

Comment: Ok but seeing God directly would be probably a strong motive to at least try to follow what He wants. Many believers follow Him because they concluded that He must exist even if we can not see Him. A direct experience would serve like this for the people being incapable to find this conclusion.

Comment: @GraySheep I think you've badly underestimated the total depravity of humankind. `He said to him, ‘If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not be convinced even if someone rises from the dead.’`(https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+16:31)

Comment: @GraySheep Most of this answer is examples of people seeing God in no uncertain terms and rejecting him anyway.

Comment: @IanGoldby For these people, I think it is over. But I am not sure, what is about the unbelievers of the today. They have no contact with the prophets. They only know about a book what they have never read, and they do not believe. Do they really have the choice to accept or reject the Prophets?

Comment: @GraySheep Did the Israelites after Moses? Or for that matter, under him?

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant Satan is a spiritual being with such knowledge than none of us. So he has also such responsibility like none of us. His decisions are final. I think it is something like if you know the "whole picture" and still decide against God, then you can not repent it later. As if he would live somehow "out of time" and his whole existence would go against God. We might see our own sins better later and repent what we did in an earlier point of time. And, ultimately, after our time ends, maybe we could ask the Savior, to recognize us, hoping in Him till the last time.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant Afaik the Israelites after Moses, still had access to the prophets. That was their everydays reality. They still became evil, it is very hard to understand. Maybe Satan attracted them into the sin. I do not really know but I think, at the time, Satan was much more strong. For example, he could directly control people. Today it can not happen (or it is rare).

Comment: @GraySheep The point is that incontrovertible evidence of God often doesn't result in faith. See the Israelites under Moses, see afterwards, e.g. them at Mt Carmel with Elijah, them with all the other prophets that did miracles, them with Jesus doing miracles, Cain, Adam & Eve, etc.

Comment: @AncientGiantPottedPlant What if they had actually believed, but the temptations were too strong? As far I know, Satan was much stronger in that time.

Comment: @GraySheep The Psalms and the NT refer to them as a faithless and rebellious generation repeatedly and lambast them for their hardness of heart despite signs and wonders. See e.g. Psa 78, Psa 95 and Heb 4, which expounds upon Psa 95. Psalm 95:8-10 ESV
"do not harden your hearts, as at Meribah, as on the day at Massah in the wilderness, [9] when your fathers put me to the test and put me to the proof, though they had seen my work. [10] For forty years I loathed that generation and said, "They are a people who go astray in their heart, and they have not known my ways.""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144495/discussion-between-ancientgiantpottedplant-and-gray-sheep).

Answer (score 1):

**God is with us!** God is indeed willing and able to be with us, His children!  However "physically" would be a trivial way of doing it. The real important essence of a man is his soul.  And Jesus had said He would dwell in our souls dynamically by the infilling of the Holy Spirit (which is God!). The **charismatic** dimension of Christianity must not be neglected in this discussion,

> The Spirit of truth...He dwelleth with you, and shall be in you.  I will not leave you comfortless, I will come to you. (John 14:17,18)

**Baptism of Holy Spirit** Jesus promised that He would not leave His disciples as orphans!  By the *Baptism of the Holy Spirit* God is able to be with us no matter where we are: in church, at home, incarcerated in jail, on the stormy main, in the adverse university... anywhere.  Whereas, if He were only physically available, he could appear to just one person at a time... unless He cloned Himself. Jesus could only be with a person, say in Cambodia, and the rest of the nations would not be with Him. Even if Jesus travelled often, continuously, He would not be able physically to meet with each and every believer every year!

This is why Jesus insisted the disciples not leave Jerusalem until they were filled with the Holy Spirit.  It is so important to each believer, as your sincere interest is exemplified by asking this question. Seek Charismatic relief as prescribed by the personable God Himself.

**At the right time** This is what the Bible stated in Galatians, *Jesus came at the right time...* I'm sure we all would realize that if Jesus came during the 21st century, with all its technological wizardry, that every miracle He did would be dismissed by sceptics as merely digital trickery!

If Jesus came sooner than the 1st century, He would not have fulfilled the *date-constrained* prophecies of the Old Testament. (See Daniel's prophecy, chapter 9) Also, Jesus had to arrive when there was a Temple (a requirement of Malachi); He had to come when genealogical records existed (to prove He was a son of David; the Temple with all its records was destroyed in 70 A.D.). He had to come when crucifixion was a mode of capital punishment (Isaiah 53).

So Jesus came at the right time...and He left in the right way...giving the *Holy Spirit Presence* to all His disciples!

**At the Right Place** Jesus came to Israel (Jerusalem) because that is where most of the supernatural prophecies were to find their fulfilment. If He showed up anywhere else, there would be no evidence for us to examine as proof of His deity. Neither Peru or Nigeria nor Germany, etc. had the Scriptures for us to test Jesus's claims.

[For important and exciting research, read Acts 1, John 14-17, 1 Corinthians 12-14]

Comment: Yes - my question was specifically why He decided to not physically stay with us, and maybe also why be present physically at that particular point in time and place in the world rather than any other one.

Comment: @Frank - God was going to appear on Earth, but no one would know who He was unless unmistakeable signs were provided.  So several prophesies were given hundreds of years in advance to pinpoint the time of His arrival.  See Daniel 9 where the Anointed One would come 490 years after the prophesy given.  The place of birth was given, as well as His type of death...and resurrection!  So Christ came at that time right on schedule.  Of course, God could have chosen any time in history, but in His wisdom, picked the Roman era (Pax Romana) when the Greek language facilitated the spread of the Gospel.